# Laravel subdomain routing working on existing domain

Tags: laravel, subdomain

I'm trying to setup a subdomain in my existing Laravel Appliation. It's working but I have 1 issue.

Looks like this:

```
Route::domain('app.example.'.app()->isProduction() ? 'com' : 'test'))->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});

Route::get('home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

https://example.com/home is working like expected. But why is https://app.example.com/home working as well? It's not in the 'domain' namespace. The order does not matter (if I put /home at the top).

Comment: is your `APP_URL=https://app.example.com/`?

Comment: Why wouldnt it? If web.php gets read when opening app.example.com the home route gets defined.

Comment: When you use `domain` you specify that the given routes will only work in that subdomain. When you don't then the routes work on any domain/subdomain. If you want to be strict then you can wrap the home route in a `Route::domain('example.com'...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel, when you define domain-based routes, it doesn't automatically restrict other routes to only the main domain. In your case, https://app.example.com/home is working because Laravel doesn't have an exclusive rule saying: "Hey, `/home` is only for the main domain and not for subdomains"

To fix this, you need to specifically tell Laravel, "This `/home` route is a main domain exclusive". You can do this by defining a domain condition for your main domain routes as well, just like you did for your subdomain :

```php
// For your subdomain
Route::domain('app.example.' . app()->isProduction() ? 'com' : 'test')->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});

// Add domain condition for main domain routes
Route::domain('example.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
```